# typescript react - Component class can't decide how many types it requires

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

Typescript has gone haywire after switching to npm and webpack to handle dependencies in my project. It has some weird issues with React.Component. It won't allow me to pass two interfaces, saying it requires one, and will complain that it doesn't have two, when it has one.

When I declare a component like this:

```
export interface IProps {
  formId: number;
}

export default class FormNavButtons extends React.Component<Iprops, {}> {...}
```

I get an error: "Generic type '*$*$RsRpExt"FromFile:(path to @types\React\index.d.ts), module=JavascriptReferencedFilesModule:Referenced external files .React.Component requires 1 type argument(s) but got 2

No idea why, nothing like that happened before I started using packages from npm. When I give it a single argument I get an error:
"Generic type Component requires 2 type argument(s)"

here is the list of my dependencies:

```
"@types/react": "^15.0.38",
"@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1",
"typescript": "^2.4.2",
"webpack": "^3.3.0"
```

how can I make this work? I have no where to even look for the problem

**EDIT**

as requested by  Vlado Pandžić, here's a complete example component. The problem concerns every last one of them, though.

```
import * as React from "react";
import FormButton from "./formButton";

export interface IProps {
    formId: number;
    save: Function;
    submitStatus: string;
    saveStatus: string;
    prevId: number;
    nextId: number;
    formNavigation: any;
}

export default class FormNavButtons extends React.Component<IProps, {}> {
    render() {
    return (
        <nav className="form-nav-buttons">
        <div className="flippable-container">
            <div className="form-nav-flippable">
                <FormButton faClass="fa-upload" label="Submit" cssClass="form-nav-submit" showsStatus={true} ajaxCallStatus={this.props.submitStatus}/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-nav-button-wrapper">
            <FormButton faClass="fa-backward" label="Previous" clickHandler={this.props.formNavigation} navId={this.props.prevId} />
            <FormButton faClass="fa-floppy-o" label="Save" clickHandler={this.props.save} showsStatus={true} ajaxCallStatus={this.props.saveStatus}/>
            <FormButton faClass="fa-ban" label="Cancel" cssClass="form-nav-cancel" />
            <FormButton faClass="fa-hand-paper-o" label="On Hold" />
            <FormButton faClass="fa-forward" label="Next" clickHandler={this.props.formNavigation} navId={this.props.nextId}/>
        </div>
        </nav>
    );
    }
}
```

and here's the list of d.ts files:

```
fi.mvc\node_modules\@types\react\index.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\@types\react-dom\index.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\@types\react-dom\server\index.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\@types\react-dom\test-utils\index.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\ajv\lib\ajv.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\hash.js\lib\hash.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\iconv-lite\lib\index.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\promise\index.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.iterable.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.collection.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.core.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.generator.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.promise.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.proxy.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.reflect.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.symbol.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2016.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2016.full.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2017.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2017.full.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2017.intl.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2017.object.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2017.sharedmemory.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es2017.string.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es5.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.es6.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.esnext.asynciterable.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.esnext.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.esnext.full.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.scripthost.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.webworker.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\protocol.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserverlibrary.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.d.ts
fi.mvc\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescriptServices.d.ts
```

Comment: Any reason for not passing formId as a regular prop ?

Comment: there are 6 other props but to keep the example simple I shortened the list to just one

Comment: Why are you using 'interface' and not regular prop ? like in this sample : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: Try to switch from awesome-typescript-loader to [ts-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader), helped for me.

Comment: unfortunately, neither of these suggestions changed anything. I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: Can you post content of whole file (imports)? What are d.ts files that exist in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the answer is rather trivial. Current @types/react version (15.0.38) broke my project, reverting to an earlier one made everything work perfectly again.

Comment: Which earlier version?

Comment: 15.0.30. Is it still broken?